error shows when using libreoffice to convert docx file to pdf
I upload docx file in html form then I want to convert this file to pdf in ubuntu server but it shows error like CalledProcessError at /add-document
Command '['libreoffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '/var/www/html/dev/media/documents/Lavender_Bay_Boatshed_Website_Testing_61gWm6r.docx', '--outdir', '/var/www/html/dev/media/documents/Lavender Bay Boatshed Website Testing.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 77.
@login_required
def add_document(request):
    title = "Add document"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES.get('file')
        check = request.POST.get('check')
        
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        print(request.POST)

        names = []
        emails = []
        for key in request.POST:
            
            if key.startswith('email_'):
                emails.append(request.POST[key])
            elif key.startswith('name_'):
                names.append(request.POST[key])
        print(emails)
        print(names)
        recipients = []
        list_of_dicts = [{'email': email, 'name': name} for email, name in zip(emails, names)]
        if file:
            if (file.name.endswith('.jpg')) or (file.name.endswith('.png')):
                obj = Documents(document=file,name=file.name,user=request.user)
                obj.save()
                image = Image.open(obj.document.path)
                iml = image.convert('RGB')
                folder = r'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\projects\Document-sign\media\documents'
                path = os.path.join(folder, file.name.split('.')[0] + '.pdf')
                os.remove(obj.document.path)
                iml.save(path)
                obj.document = f"documents/{file.name.split('.')[0]}.pdf"
                obj.save()
                os.remove(obj.document.path)
                if check:
                    request.session['check'] = False
                    return redirect('sign_document')
                else:
                    recipients.append({'emails':list_of_dicts,'subject':subject,'message':message})
                    request.session['recipients'] = recipients
                    request.session['check'] = True
                    return redirect('make_envelope')
                
            elif file.name.endswith('.docx'):
                obj = Documents(document=file, name=file.name, user=request.user)
                obj.save()

                # Define paths
                path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'documents')
                input_path = obj.document.path
                

                # Run LibreOffice conversion
                try:
                    result = subprocess.run(
                        ['libreoffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', input_path, '--outdir', path],
                        check=True,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE
                    )
                    print(result.stdout)
                    print(result.stderr)
                except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                    print("Error occurred:", e.stderr)
                    raise

                # Remove the original DOCX file
                os.remove(input_path)

                # Update the document path to the converted PDF
                obj.document = f"documents/{file.name.split('.')[0]}.pdf"
                obj.save()
                
                if check:
                    request.session['check'] = False
                    return redirect('sign_document')
                else:
                    recipients.append({'emails':list_of_dicts,'subject':subject,'message':message})
                    request.session['recipients'] = recipients
                    request.session['check'] = True
                    return redirect('make_envelope')
            else:
                obj = Documents(document=file,name=file.name,user=request.user)
                obj.save()
                if check:
                    
                    request.session['check'] = False
                    return redirect('sign_document')
                else:
                    recipients.append({'emails':list_of_dicts,'subject':subject,'message':message})
                    print(recipients)
                    request.session['recipients'] = recipients
                    request.session['check'] = True
                    return redirect('make_envelope')   
            
    context = {'title':title}
    return render(request, 'myapp/add_document.html',context=context)



Put the print statements in the exception handler as well. There may be significant information there, especially print(result.stderr)

Googling for "libreoffice headless 77" I get the impression that an exit code 77 usually indicates a permission issue, see e.g. here.

Yes, its problem of permission. unable to create directory '/var/www/.cache/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly. this error shows in error.log file

We might need some additional information. Try to start with the following:
1- Verify the path (obj.document.path) to the file you want to convert is correct. You can do this by by just adding a os.path.isfile(obj.document.path) before calling libreoffice.
2- Ensure libreoffice is installed in your environment: libreoffice --version
3- Try to use --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export isntead of just --convert-to pdf
4- Make sure the output dir exists
5- Make sure there is no GUI instances open of libreoffice

I make changes '--convert-to', 'pdf' to '--convert-to' 'pdf:writer_pdf_Export' and run again but it shows 'bufsize must be an integer' error in browser
